# is linkedIn-j compatible on android Samsung GALAXY 2.3.6

Tags: android, linkedin-j

I'm trying to integrate linkedin using linkedin-j or/and scribe_1.3 on my devide Samsung Galaxy S (android version 2.3.6) and I want to know if it's compatible.

my app always crashes on:

Token liToken = oAuthService.getRequestToken(callback); with server failed error.

but then I prove to run my app on simulator 2.3.3 and it runs perfectly

why? it is not compatible??

please I need to know If I have alternative to get the integration of linkedIn on my app.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this api for linkedIn. It helps me to post status and get contacts. Faced lot of issues with linkedin-j

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Comment: I think that it's not possible